# CSS grid - hide a grid-area on click of a button

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm trying to create a sidenav that can be shown/hidden on a button click. 
I have used `grid-area` and `grid-template-areas` for the layout.
I have a `grid-area` for sidenav. I want the `grid-area` also to be hidden when the sidenav is hidden. Is it possible to achieve this?

The full code is here - https://codepen.io/devi_ks/pen/Ebddwo

```js
$("a").on("click", function() {
  $("#sidenav").hide();
  return false;
});
```

```css
#header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#sidenav {
  grid-area: sidenav;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#content {
  grid-area: content;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "sidenav content"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header">
  <a href="#">Click me</a>
</div>
<div id="sidenav">
  <ul>
    <li> menu 1</li>
    <li> menu 2</li>
    <li> menu 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  Some content goes here....
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `grid-area`, so the place for the side nav is allocated at start. If you hide (or even delete) the side nav, that won't change anything about this. You have to do a little trick:
Set the width for the first column to 0 and change the `grid-gap` because otherwise you will have a (not needed) gap at the left.

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
  $("#sidenav").hide(true);
  $("body").css("grid-template-columns", "0px 2fr");
  $("body").css("grid-gap", "10px 0px");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: If you want to reactivate the sidenav, you had to show the sidenav, set the grid-template-columns back to  "0.5fr 2fr" and the grid-gap back to "10px".

Comment: there has to be a better way!!  This cannot be the answer.  having to reset the grid-template-columns to '0' for the grid area that gets hidden, is way too tedious.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").on("click", function(){
     if($("#sidenav").is(":visible")){
       $("#sidenav").hide();
       $("#content").hide();
     }else{
       $("#sidenav").show();
       $("#content").show();
     }
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: You disable the content but this was not intended from Devi. He wants just to eliminate the space from the hidden sidenav. For this look at my answer.

Comment: @wilson Thanks for your response. What Sascha says is what is expected.